# find minimum disconnected components in a straight directed graph

Tags: graph

**how to find minimum number of disconnected components in a directed graph if all  edges are given consider for graph with 8 nodes.**
construct directed graph by choosing edges very wisely such that it has minimum number of disconnected components.
I tried with all possible pairs ,here is my code

```
map<ll,ll>v;
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
for(i=j;i<n-1;i++)
{
    if(mp[{p[j],p[i+1]}]==s && v[p[i+1]]!=-1)
     {
        c[p[j]]=p[i+1];
        v[p[i+1]]=-1;
        break;
     }

}
map<ll,ll>u;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
if(c[i]==0)
count++;
}
```